# Excel Nested IF with INDEX & MATCH

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match

I have two tables Store Detail and Master

**Store Detail**

```
   A        B          C
Division  Region   Store No.
            1B       2134
            88       9876
            88       5566
...
```

**Master**

```
   A        B         C
Division  Region   Store No.
10R46     88       5566
10R46     1B       2134
100R91    88       9876
```

The idea is to get the Division number from the Master for the 'Store Detail' table by Indexing and Matching with Division and Store No. from the Master... I want to add a IF also...so If Region in the Store Detail Table is equal to 88 then put 88 in the Division cell.

I have tried combining the Index(If...),Match() but I keep getting countless errors, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are the store numbers unique in column `C`?

Comment: @Zac Yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the store numbers are not enough to identify a division, then create an additional column where you combine the region and store number into one string. In `D2` you would put (and copy down):

```
=B2 & "|" & C2
```

Add this column `D` in both sheets. You can hide those extra columns if you want.

Then the problem to fill the Division column translates to a simple lookup. In `A2` you would put (and copy down):

```
=INDEX(Master!A:A, MATCH(D2, Master!D:D,0))
```

To add an exception as an `IF`, just do:

```
=IF(B2="88", "88", INDEX(Master!A:A, MATCH(D2, Master!D:D,0)))
```

If column B (sometimes) contains numeric types, then convert those to string types first, or do this in the formula:

```
=IF(B2&""="88", "88", INDEX(Master!A:A, MATCH(D2, Master!D:D,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEX`/`AGGERGATE` in single formula:

```
=IF(B2=88,88,INDEX($G$2:$G$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/((B2=$H$2:$H$4)*(C2=$I$2:$I$4)))*ROW($G$2:$G$4)-1,1)))
```

[image]